# Should the 2500th anniversary of the Battle of Thermopylae (480 BC) be 2020 or 2021?

Tags: date

[*The Economist* (2020-10-10)](https://www.economist.com/europe/2020/10/10/why-tourists-shun-salamis-site-of-a-great-sea-battle):

> 2,500 years ago a small Greek fleet thrashed a huge Persian one. ...

> It is the 2,500th anniversary of one of the greatest naval battles of the ancient world. In the early autumn of 480BC, in the strait between Salamis and the mainland, a few hundred Greek triremes (warships with three banks of oars and bronze battering-rams) defeated a much larger Persian armada.

However, there was no [Year Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero). So, shouldn't

1. 2,500 years ago be 481 BC?
2. And 480 BC + 2500 years = AD 2021, so that the 2500th anniversary of this battle be AD 2021?

Comment: Possibly to avoid a clash with the 200th anniversary of the beginning of the Greek war of independence in 1821? Or perhaps simply because 2020 + 480 = 2,500 years = a nice bunch of round numbers so let's keep it like that as it's close enough. Or maybe someone boobed and it's too late to admit it. Maybe worth contacting the Greek Ministry of Culture?

Comment: Obviously it should be 2021 but this isn't a history question - it's a political decision by the Greeks, which is a field (politics) notoriously not bound by historicity. One might speculate on the financial benefits to the sale of commemorative memorabilia..... BTW, not that it makes a difference since they both take place in 480 BC, but your title references [Thermopylae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Thermopylae) but the body & quotes are talking about the [Battle of Salamis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Salamis)?

Comment: As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for History.SE as it is more of a maths/politics question, and essentially a duplicate of this more generalized question: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/47246/time-span-of-a-decade/. Perhaps there could be a history question here (is there grounds to challenge the conventional dating of the battles?) but it would have to be edited.

Comment: The ancients did not possess a concept of zero, which is why they used [inclusive counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting#Inclusive_counting); this can still be seen, until this very day, within traditional Christian calendars, such as the Greek Orthodox one, wherein the Sunday following Easter, for instance, is called the *second* Sunday after, instead of the *first*; etc. Thus, the first anniversary being the event itself, as it were, according to this system of reckoning, its 2,500th commemoration does indeed fall within the current year, since, as you noted, there is no year zero.

Comment: @Lucian - the ancients did have a concept of zero, they just thought of it differently than we do. A zero on an abacus is ... what? Don't move a stone. Today is Sunday (1) next Sunday is 2.